# Positioning win-forms track-bar / resizing

Tags: winforms, c#-4.0, trackbar

I'm having an issue with a Win-forms Track bar extending beyond the background of the user control. I have it anchored to Bottom, Left, Right. I can set the sizes manually to make it stay in-bounds, but lose the re-sizing ability.

I would like to have the track-bar expand with re-sizing of the form. This is the standard track-bar control for win-forms. I have included a picture below. The track-bar in question is right below the birds. Its a little hard to see but the track-bar extends way beyond the scope of the window.

[image: track-bar]

Comment: This is a child of a frame? how the frame is setup? maybe the frame is also autosize?

Comment: this user control is a child of a tab control, which is the child of the main window. The track-bar is set to auto size and the form above is not. I played with the settings and received the same result

Comment: The way you are telling, then it will grow forever, because anchor is not the same as docked. You anchor it to grow or shrink according to the parent, but you can make it any wide you want at start.. you better has a maximum value according to the form size to avoid it..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmm, yeah you wouldn't want it going to the birds.

Use the [`Anchor`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.anchor.aspx) and [`Dock`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.dock.aspx) properties of the control to adhere it to the edges of your container form.

You can either set them at design time in the Properties Window, or via code that you place in your form's constructor method.

Comment: I tried the design time and got it working. I just set the width according to the width of the control above it.